# Simulate multi user access to multi URLs to submit Forms

Tags: jmeter, selenium-grid

I want to develop loading testing tool for scenario below:

1. Read the list URLs from the listUrls.txt which access to WebForms
2. Run each URL on the one window/tab on a browser and click Submit button the same time.
   I research the selenium webDriver and Jmeter but it's hard to build this. Have any solutions to simulation this?

Comment: You need to read URLs of the webforms and then submit it. It is one and the same scenario or two different. 1. Read URL--What is next then? 2. Submit webforms..Please clarify. if you need to read the URLs of webforms from csv and then need to submit the same.It is possible using jmeter but there is not browser interaction required here for load testing. Any special requirement to use selenium webdriver for load.

Comment: Thank Sunny_Teo for your advices but I’m a new to automation testing so I’m not much experiences to develop this scenario by selenium webdriver. Like you say I simulated sucessful this on Jmeter but Selenium I dont know how to build up.Would you give me a short code for case read txt file and run url on each browser the same time? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Below snapshot is using csv to get the URLs and opening them in a browser using webdriver sampler. I have use csv data set config to fetch the URLs from the csv file.
You need to config browser using Firefox/Chrome/InternetExplorer driver config based on your choice. Firefox is easy but other two requires selenium browser exe to launch the browser.

[image]

To enter data in the webform check the below to get familiar with the syntax:-

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait);//WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();//captures sampler’s start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get('http://duckduckgo.com')//opens website specified in 'http://duckduckgo.com'
WDS.log.info("Sample ended - navigated to duckduckgo.com");

var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_form_input_homepage'))//saves search field into searchField 
searchField.click()//clicks search field
searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter'])//types word “blazemeter” in field
WDS.log.info("Searched for BlazeMeter");

var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_button_homepage'))//Find Search button
button.click()//Click Search Button
WDS.log.info("Clicked on the search button");

var link = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('#r1-0 > div > h2 > a.result__a > b'))//also saves selector as variable but uses CSS.
link.click()//Click the search result's Link

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

For more information on how to setup and and write code for the webforms...check the below links:-
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421245-Selenium-Webdriver-Based-Testing
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler

Hope this helps.